# How to join stream created from one topic to KTable derived(as aggregate operation) from other topic

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Problem : How to join stream created from TOPIC_2(in step2) to KTable stateTable(in step1 of the format ).

Goal: After join operation if we change the state of AlarmState( value of the KTable stateTable) object the same state should be reflected in the stateTable(part of step1)

There is KTable(as stateTable) described in Step1(created from TOPIC_1) 
There is another topic TOPIC_2 where data is generated(in step2)
Key of stateTable and generated data in TOPIC_2 are same

Step1.

```
final KStream<String, MetricBasicMessage> basicMsgStream = builder.stream("TOPIC_1",
                Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), new JSONSerde<>()));

KTable <String, AlarmState> stateTable = 
         builder.stream("TOPIC_1",Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), new JSONSerde<>()))
                .flatMapValues(...)
                .filter(...)
                .map(...)
                .groupByKey(...)
                .aggregate(...);

final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), <streamsConfiguration>);
        streams.start();
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));
```

Step2.

```
String keyToJoinWithState = key.substring(0, index);

producer.send("TOPIC_2", keyToJoinWithState, new NotificationMessage(taskType, thresh),"NOTIIFCATION_MESSAGE");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to join stream with some table you just need to call

`KStream::join(final KTable<K, VT> table, final ValueJoiner<? super V, ? super VT, ? extends VR> joiner);`

It will be something like that:

```java
KStream<String, String> stream2 = builder.<String, NotificationMessage >stream("TOPIC_2", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), new NotificationMessageSerdes()));
stream2.join(stateTable, (v1, v2) -> ??? /* How to join values from Stream and KTable */).to("output2");
```

Comment: Your suggestion i tried already and it is working if we join KTable and Stream created from Topic but here KTable is derived from another topic as aggregate operation. Getting the following exception "org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TopologyException: Invalid topology: StateStore AlarmState is not added yet." if i want to achieve my use case.

Comment: @OmSpatel, I think it is not related with a join. It seems, that your Processors uses state stores that are not register, Could you attach the source code?

Comment: Thanks Wardziniak for your reply...It worked after adding StateStore object.                              
  final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
  
  KeyValueBytesStoreSupplier  storeSupplier = Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("AlarmState");
  StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, JSONSerdeCompatible>> storeBuilder = Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(storeSupplier, Serdes.String(), new JSONSerde<>());
  builder.addStateStore(storeBuilder);

Comment: @OmSpatel, If it helps, you can upvote and/or accept answer.